# Long to wide with columns as date using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple dates for an id. I want to create a column out for all dates that will flag that id. I tried this with pivot it doesn't work. It says it can't use date as columns.

```
data = {'id': [1, 1, 1,  2, 2,], 'dt': ['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02','2021-01-02', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

another approach i took was to create a rank. and then unstack it. but there are lot of issues with it as I don't get sorted dates.

```
df['rank'] = df.sort_values('dt').groupby('id').cumcount+1
df.set_index(['id', 'dt'], append = True).unstack()
```

What can I try next? Or is there a simpler approach?

Comment: It would be lot easier for us to help you if you add the sample dataframe along with your expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I Understand Correctly:

try:

```
df['dt']=pd.to_datetime(df['dt'])
df['rank']=df.sort_values('dt').groupby('id').cumcount()+1
df['dt']=df['dt'].astype(str)
df=df.pivot('id','dt','rank').rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index()
```

output of `df`:

```
    id  2021-01-01  2021-01-02  2021-01-03
0   1   1.0         2.0         NaN
1   2   NaN         1.0         2.0
```

OR(Since you didn't provided expected output so not sure which one you want)

via `crosstab()`:

```
df=pd.crosstab(df['id'],df['dt']).rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index()
```

output of `df`:

```
    id  2021-01-01  2021-01-02  2021-01-03
0   1       1       1               0
1   2       0       1               1
```

Comment: hey thanks a lot crosstab work perfectly. i have duplicates in data like this. it throws df=df.pivot('id','dt','rank').rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index()

Comment: @ChirayuChamoli yes if you have duplicates then pivot throws an error 'can't reindex from duplicate axis'......btw if your query is silved then you can try considering accepting the answer.....Thnx **:)**